# 下記のようなXMLのデータをswiftでパースしたい。 NSXMLParserを使用するつもりです。 <author> <dc:title> <dc:publisher>を配列に格納？しparse.comにデータを保存したいです。 どのようにコードを書けばいいでしょうか。

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

下記のようなXMLのデータをswiftでパースしたい。  NSXMLParserを使用するつもりです。     を配列に格納？しparse.comにデータを保存したいです。   どのようにコードを書けばいいでしょうか。

```
result: '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss xmlns:dcterms="http://purl.org/dc/terms/"xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:dcndl="http://ndl.go.jp/dcndl/terms/" version="2.0" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:openSearch="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearchrss/1.0/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#" xmlns:dcmitype="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/">
<channel>
<title>9784088701141 - 国立国会図書館サーチ OpenSearch</title>
<link>http://iss.ndl.go.jp/api/opensearch?isbn=9784088701141</link>
<description>Search results for isbn=9784088701141 </description>
<language>ja</language>
<openSearch:totalResults>1</openSearch:totalResults>
<openSearch:startIndex>1</openSearch:startIndex>
<openSearch:itemsPerPage></openSearch:itemsPerPage>
<item>
  <title>バクマン。</title>
  <link>http://iss.ndl.go.jp/books/R100000002-I000011011591-00</link>
<description>
<![CDATA[<p>10 (表現力と想像力),集英社,9784088701141</p>
<ul><li>タイトル： バクマン。</li>
<li>タイトル（読み）： バクマン</li>
<li>責任表示： 大場つぐみ 原作,小畑健 漫画,</li>
<li>シリーズ名： ジャンプ・コミックス</li>
<li>シリーズ名（読み）： ジャンプ コミックス</li>
<li>NDC(9)： 726.1</li>
</ul>]]>
</description>
  <author>大場つぐみ 原作,小畑健 漫画,</author>
  <category>本</category>
  <guid isPermaLink="true">http://iss.ndl.go.jp/books/R100000002-I000011011591-00</guid>
  <pubDate>Fri, 05 Nov 2010 09:00:00 +0900</pubDate>
  <dc:title>バクマン。</dc:title>
  <dcndl:titleTranscription>バクマン</dcndl:titleTranscription>
  <dc:creator>大場つぐみ 原作</dc:creator>
  <dc:creator>小畑健 漫画</dc:creator>
  <dcndl:volume>10 (表現力と想像力)</dcndl:volume>
  <dcndl:seriesTitle>ジャンプ・コミックス</dcndl:seriesTitle>
  <dcndl:seriesTitleTranscription>ジャンプ コミックス   </dcndl:seriesTitleTranscription>
  <dc:publisher>集英社</dc:publisher>
  <dcterms:issued xsi:type="dcterms:W3CDTF">2010</dcterms:issued>
  <dc:identifier xsi:type="dcndl:ISBN">9784088701141</dc:identifier>
  <dc:identifier xsi:type="dcndl:JPNO">21829876</dc:identifier>
  <dc:subject xsi:type="dcndl:NDLC">Y84</dc:subject>
  <dc:subject xsi:type="dcndl:NDC9">726.1</dc:subject>
  <rdfs:seeAlso rdf:resource="http://id.ndl.go.jp/bib/000011011591"/>
　</item>
 </channel>
</rss>
```

Comment: `NSXMLParser`クラスとParseに出てくる`PFObject`クラスについてはどこまで知ってんの？

Comment: Swift で該当データをパースすることと、 parse.com にデータを保存することは別の問題(質問)のような気がします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**一冊ごとのデータを入れた辞書**(anInfo)を**配列に溜めて**(informations)それをParseのクラウドへセーブする。この解析ではitemタグでanInfoの内容を区切ってる

このコードはParseのセットアップができてりゃXMLがプロジェクトのバンドルに「test.xml」として存在すれば動く

```
import UIKit
import Parse

class ViewController: UIViewController, NSXMLParserDelegate {

  var XMLParser: NSXMLParser?
  var XMLParserTargetElementName: String?
  var parseObject: PFObject?
  var informations: [AnyObject]?
  var anInfo: [String: String]?

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.parse()
  }

  func parse() {
    let url = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("test", withExtension: "xml")
    self.XMLParser = NSXMLParser(contentsOfURL: url)
    self.XMLParser?.delegate = self
    self.XMLParserTargetElementName = nil

    self.parseObject = PFObject(className: "BookInfo")

    var success = self.XMLParser?.parse()
    if (success == true) {
      self.parseObject!.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        println(self.parseObject!.objectId)
      }
    }
  }

  func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
    self.XMLParserTargetElementName = elementName

    if (elementName == "item") {
      self.informations = []
      self.anInfo = [String: String]()
    }
  }

  func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?) {
    self.XMLParserTargetElementName = nil

    if (elementName == "item") {
      println(self.anInfo)
      self.informations?.append(self.anInfo!)
      self.parseObject!["item"] = self.informations
    }
  }

  func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, foundCharacters string: String?) {
    if (self.XMLParserTargetElementName == "author" ||
      self.XMLParserTargetElementName == "dc:title" ||
      self.XMLParserTargetElementName == "dc:publisher") {
        self.anInfo![self.XMLParserTargetElementName!] = string
    }
  }
}
```

クラウドのデータブラウザでこうなる

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

PFObjectを使ってれば分かると思うが同じobjectIdを自分で指定しなければインスタンスを作ってセーブするたびに新規データ扱いでクラウドに追加されるから気をつけろよ